# Update created record in Custom Workflow Activity -CRM -C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have created new entity.

From that entity i call Custom Workflow Activity entity that creates opportunity.
It works, but additionally I have to change some fields on created opportunity.
(I have to add opportunity products, and have to change price list for each opportunity).

As a test I tried to Update account field after creation, but it failed field. When i populate this account field before creation, it works, so it is not about that.
Here is the part of the code:

```
          Entity entity = null;
        if (context.InputParameters != null && context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
           entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
        }
        else
        {
            entity = service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, ((Guid)context.PrimaryEntityId), new ColumnSet(true));
        }
        Entity opportunity = new Entity("opportunity");
        string name = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject");
        opportunity["name"] = name;
        opportunityId = service.Create(opportunity);
        EntityReference accountlookup = (EntityReference)entity.Attributes["ad_sendto"];
        Guid accountId = accountlookup.Id;

        opportunity["parentaccountid"] = new EntityReference("account", accountId);
        service.Update(opportunity);
```

To repeat, it creates opportunity, but it doesn't work for update, is there any other way to do this, or do I have some errors here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you are trying to update `opportunity` entity which does not have a primary key (opportunityid) set.

Instead of updating the opportunity after it was created, why not just assign the `parentaccountid` during the create operation?

```
var opportunity = new Entity("opportunity");
opportunity["name"] = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject"); ;
opportunity["parentaccountid"] = entity.Attributes["ad_sendto"];
opportunityId = service.Create(opportunity);
```

For future references, if you ever have to update an entity that was just created or any entity for that matter:

```
var opportunityToUpdate = new Entity("opportunity")
{
    Id = opportunityId
};
opportunityToUpdate["parentaccountid"] = entity.Attributes["ad_sendto"];
service.Update(opportunityToUpdate);
```

Comment: `opportunity["parentaccountid"] = entity.Attributes["ad_sendto"];`
`service.Update(opportunityToUpdate);`
Last two rows, did you mean `opportunity["parentaccountid"] `or `opportunityToUpdate["parenaccountid"]`, befor Update?

Comment: You are correct, copy paste error, updated the answer.